# Sonarqube Doesn't Mark Violations from Custom Rules Plugin

Tags: java, sonarqube

I've been trying for a few weeks to get sonarqube to work with custom plugins and have hit multiple dead ends. I am using [this example](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples). If I understand correctly, all I should have to do is `mvn clean package` on the directory and then copy the jar generated into /etc/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/. When I do this, the sonarqube server recognizes the new rules (including snapshots below).

Before adding plugin:
[image: Before]

After adding plugin:
[image: After]

It seems like the sonar-scanner also recognizes the plugins since I see the following as output whenever I run the scanner the first time after moving the jar into the plugins directory. You'll notice the last line of this has the scanner "Downloading" the custom rules jar.

`INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/3.0.3.778/libexec/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
INFO: Java 1.8.0_144 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64
INFO: User cache: /Users/jareddembrun/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=104ms
INFO: User cache: /Users/jareddembrun/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=10ms
INFO: Download java-custom-rules-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I am running this on a single java file. Since one of the rules (the one called [MyCustomSubscriptionRule](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/blob/master/java-custom-rules/src/main/java/org/sonar/samples/java/checks/MyCustomSubscriptionRule.java)) seems to be checking that there is no method taking exactly one parameter and returning a something of the same type as that parameter, I do this in my java file:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String x = echo("Hello World");
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    private static String echo(String in)
    {
        return in;
    }
}
```

When I run the scan, it actually does analyze the file, and returns three other "code smells," which I can see in the webapp:
[image]

But, as you can see, none of these are the custom rule. Is there some step I missing here? Am I not understanding what the custom rule is doing? I have exhausted a lot of different routes, both for javascript and java checkers. All have seemed to be dead ends. Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you add your custom rules to the [quality profile](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles) which is used to analyse your project?

Comment: I have not. I don't understand this documentation. What to I add and to what files? I try to do the bulk change, but I can't use it because the field comes up with "No matches found," even when I start typing Java. If I try to apply it to 'Java' anyway, it tells me the "targetProfile" parameter is missing. How do I find the targetProfile parameter for a given profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules must be added to a quality profile. Go to quality profiles on the sonarqube webapp. Log in at the top right (user=admin, pass=admin, by default), click "create" at the top right and make a new profile.

Once the new profile is made, you can add it as a child to the default profile for the language you are concerned with. Then, also add it to the project (you only have to add it to the project to make this work). Go to the rule you are concerned with and activate it in the new profile. Rerun the scan, and you should see that the rule has raised an issue as expected.